# fail to convert .ui to .py file (PyQt6)

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyqt6, uic

I've created an ui file using the QT Designer in PyQt6 and recieved the following error:
*TypeError: ('Wrong base class of toplevel widget', (<class '**main**.UI'>, 'QMainWindow'))*

after trying to convert (ui to py) the file using the uic library:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt6 import uic
import sys


class UI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        uic.loadUi("tests_window.ui", self)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Also, recived this error:

*CommandNotFoundException*

after trying to use "pyuic6 -x input.ui -o output.py" in terminal.

I figure the two cases are related somehow, couldn't find any solution in previous topics and the packages were installed using pip.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The two problems are not related. The first is caused because you created a *main window* in designer, but you're subclassing QWidget instead, so you need to change the inheritance to QMainWindow. The second may be caused by the fact that you have not installed pyuic (or didn't install it properly, or you're using a venv). Try with `pip install pyqt6-tools`.